# How to check endpoints?

Tags: java, spring, list, directory, singleton

I have a basic application in SpringBoot
Using Singleton, I created a mechanism to count endpoits on the server and write them to the list
I would like the application to be able to run locally and check endpoints on different sites.

How best to go about it? What components (beans?) Do I need?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I shouldn't have been destroying the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
val folder: Array [File] = new File(dir)
.listFiles
.filter(_.isDirectory)
```

If you are looking for all the files in each folder:

```
val nameOfFiles = for (file <- folder) yield file.listFiles()
```

If you are looking for specific file type in each folder:

```
val nameOfFilesFiltered = for (file <- folder) yield file.listFiles().filter(_.getName.endsWith(".PNG"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a function that extracts all files for any Directory, you need a recursive function that also handles these cases:

```
root
 -- file1.txt
 -- dir1
      -- file2.txt
      -- dir 2
           -- file3.txt
```

Here an example:

```
def filterArtifacts(dir: File): Seq[File] = {
    dir.listFiles()
      .flatMap {
        case f if f.isDirectory => filterArtifacts(f)
        case f if f.getName.startsWith(".") => Seq.empty // ignore hidden files.
        case f => Seq(f)
      }
  }
```

You can use it like:

```
filterArtifacts(new File( "/Scala-App/Photos/all/" ))
 .foreach(f => println(f.getName))
```